# How to check 'if condition' for each item in a list

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm trying to check a certain list against very a very specific set of rules.
In this particular example, I have a list of exit codes and I want to check if the test failed. The test fails if even one of the exit codes isn't 0.

My current implementation:

```
for exit_code in result_list:
    if exit_code is not 0:
        raise TestFailed
```

Question: is it possible to cram the first two lines into one? Is it preferable to do so?

Comment: IMHO using `any` does not make your code more readable. I personally recommend not to use the implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` as it makes the code less readable. I prefer explicitness. The only advantage of `any` might be better performance, because the loop is inside the library function. But this is likely premature optimization and/or not your performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use `any` or `all` like this:

```
>>> any(exit_code !=0 for exit_code in result_list)
True
>>> all(exit_code==0 for exit_code in result_list)
False
```

since 1 is True and 0 is false in python.

`any(result_list)` will try to find any 1 element that is not 0(True)

Comment: Marked as correct answer for not only giving the right solution, but giving two similar methods that I wasn't familiar with. As well as explaining what each function returns.

Comment: using `all(result_list)` is wrong here. You MUST negate the elements before passing to `all`. `error_found = not all(not i for i in result_list)`. The negation of the list before passing to `all` cannot be omitted.

Comment: @Markus using `all` here is a bit risky as it wont pass all cases. For example:  `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` --> `not all()` would result in `True`, your code would also result in `True`, we cannot use `all` here. Kindly remove the down vote.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `any`:

```
if any(exit_code != 0 for exit_code in result_list):
    raise TestFailed
```

Note that the above method assumes that you are also checking for values that are equivalent to boolean `False` (such as `None`, or `False`!). If you are sure that your `result_list` only contains numbers, you can shorten it a little more:

```
if any(result_list):
    raise TestFailed
```

Comment: I marked @ritesht93's answer as the correct one, but upvoted this answer as well, since it includes a very nice explanation on how to implement this. I really liked the second, shorter implementation. So neat!